# select in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, aggregate-functions

I have a table follow:

```
ID  |  first  |  end
--------------------
a   |      1  |    3
b   |      3  |    8
c   |      8  |   10
```

I want to select follow:

```
 ID  |  first  |  end
---------------------
a-c  |      1  |   10
```

But i can't do it. Please! help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
SELECT MIN(t.id)+'-'+MAX(t.id) AS ID,
       MIN(t.[first]) AS first,
       MAX(t.[end]) AS [end]
  FROM dbo.YOUR_TABLE t
```

But *please*, ***do not use reserved words like "end" for column names***.

Comment: I see. But it i have a table follow:
ID first end
a   1     3
b   3     8
c   8     10
d   15    19
e   10    12
f   19    23

i think it false.
Because i want to select

ID  first  end
a-e  3      12
d-f  15     23

Comment: @Vuong: I think, though, you can extend this idea to meet your needs. If you add a calculated column to your select to generate your grouping headers (consider using a `case` statement to calculate the column), then group on the calculation, you can still apply `MIN` and `MAX` as suggested here.

Comment: @Voung Mao: That's a different data set than what you posted in your question - if that was what you deal with, you should post the question with that detail because anyone has to read your comment to know about other criteria.  It's also unclear how you know there are two groups in that data set, or where they start & end.

Comment: @kbrimington: You're 100% correct.  Now if only we knew what the logic was for how Vuoung is grouping...  See how it's "a-e", and "d-f"? :/

Comment: first. I thank you.
to get ideas from a - e and since b - d is as follows:

we have: a is "First" is "1" and "end" is "3", similar to the "b" is "3" and "8"
Should "end" of "a" match "first" of "b", we say they are "ab" from "3-8"
Please help ease fears. Because I need it. thanks everyone

Comment: What I think he's trying to get is chains of rows where you have start -> end=start -> end=start -> end (etc) and then find the endpoints of those chains.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this using a [recursive Common Table Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx) as follows, especially if you're not expecting very long chains of records:

```
WITH Ancestors AS
(
    SELECT
        InitRow.[ID] AS [Ancestor],
        InitRow.[ID],
        InitRow.[first],
        InitRow.[end],
        0 AS [level],
        '00000' + InitRow.[ID] AS [hacky_level_plus_ID]
    FROM
        YOUR_TABLE AS InitRow
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE AS PrevRow
            WHERE PrevRow.[end] = InitRow.[first]
        )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        ParentRow.Ancestor,
        ChildRow.[ID],
        ChildRow.[first],
        ChildRow.[end],
        ParentRow.level + 1 AS [level],
        -- Avoids having to build the recursive structure more than once.
        -- We know we will not be over 5 digits since CTEs have a recursion
        -- limit of 32767.
        RIGHT('00000' + CAST(ParentRow.level + 1 AS varchar(4)), 5)
            + ChildRow.[ID] AS [hacky_level_plus_ID]
    FROM
        Ancestors AS ParentRow
        INNER JOIN YOUR_TABLE AS ChildRow
            ON ChildRow.[first] = ParentRow.[end]
)
SELECT
    Ancestors.Ancestor + '-' + SUBSTRING(MAX([hacky_level_plus_ID]),6,10) AS [IDs],
-- Without the [hacky_level_plus_ID] column, you need to do it this way:
--  Ancestors.Ancestor + '-' +
--      (SELECT TOP 1 Children.ID FROM Ancestors AS Children
--      WHERE Children.[Ancestor] = Ancestors.[Ancestor]
--      ORDER BY Children.[level] DESC) AS [IDs],
    MIN(Ancestors.[first]) AS [first],
    MAX(Ancestors.[end]) AS [end]
FROM
    Ancestors
GROUP BY
    Ancestors.Ancestor
-- If needed, add OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767)
```

A quick explanation of what each part does:

The `WITH Ancestors AS (...)` clause creates a Common Table Expression (basically a subquery) with the name `Ancestors`.  The first `SELECT` in that expression establishes a baseline: all the rows that have no matching entry prior to it.

Then, the second `SELECT` is where the recursion kicks in.  Since it references `Ancestors` as part of the query, it uses the rows it has already added to the table and then performs a join with new ones from `YOUR_TABLE`.  This will recursively find more and more rows to add to the end of each chain.

The last clause is the `SELECT` that uses this recursive table we've built up.  It does a simple `GROUP BY` since we've saved off the original ID in the `Ancestor` column, so the start and end are a simple `MIN` and `MAX`.

The tricky part is figuring out the ID of the last row in the chain.  There are two ways to do it, both illustrated in the query.  You can either join back with the recursive table, in which case it will build the recursive table all over again, or you can attempt to keep track of the last item as you go.  (If building the recursive list of chained records is expensive, you definitely want to minimize the number of times you need to do that.)

The way it keeps track as it goes is to keep track of its position in the chain (the `level` column -- notice how we add 1 each time we recurse), zero-pad it, and then stick the ID at the end.  Then, getting the item with the max `level` is simply a `MAX` followed by stripping the `level` data out.

If the CTE has to recurse too much, it will generate an error, but I believe you can tweak that using the `MAXRECURSION` option.  The default is 100.  If you have to set it higher than that, you may want to consider not using a recursive CTE to do this.

This also doesn't handle malformed data very well.  If you have two records with the same `first` or a record where `first` == `end`, then this won't work right and you may have to tweak the join conditions inside the CTE or go with another approach.

This isn't the only way to do it.  I believe it would be easier to follow if you built a custom procedure and did all the steps manually.  But this has the advantage of operating in a single statement.

Comment: thanks you so much. do you answer simple than? I only use small database.